# How to implement mouse pointer and it's operations on android programatically

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a remote controller software. It is based on the idea that a smartphone, which runs android operating system on it, can remotely control a smartbox over WiFi. Problem here is, smartbox, which is connected to the Tv also runs android on it.

I am now working on mouse implementation for the both client-side (phone) and server-side (smartbox). Any coordinate changings on the touch screen of the phone will be transmitted to smartbox via UDP protocol over WiFi and smartbox will process the relevant coordinate changings on it. Problem is, I do not know how to show mouse pointer on android that runs in smartbox and how to manipulate setting/moving mouse cursor. I search this issue a lot on the internet but all the resources are based on android-to-Pc, there is no even one android-to-android remote controlling project like this.

As I mentioned before, if you give me any idea about how to implement and operate mouse pointer on android 2.2 (froyo) operating system programatically, I will appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there is no Android-to-Android remote controlling because Android does not support mouse pointers natively.

Comment: Unfortunately you are wrong because there is a mouse module on kernel that enables itself when you plug a mouse from usb port. It is up to developers to prune that module from kernel. It is about implementation. As I said before, when you plug mouse from usb, a mouse cursor appears and you can use mouse on android. This is the proof that android 2.2 (froyo) has mouse module implmented on it's kernel. And I am asking for a way to use it programatically ( not necessarily through SDK)

Comment: I didn't say that Android doesn't support mouse controllers, I said that mouse pointers are not supported by the framework.

Comment: Maybe you could access the device using JNI. Or you can try accessing the device from /dev/mouse. See http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/6d3329d7a7425ebe

Comment: But there must be a way to use functionalities of mouse pointer even if it is on the low-level.

Comment: Yes, see my previous comment.